# how to assing the value of a range to a function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am using a function which takes two of the inputs from specific cells which are defined as ranges.
When I run the code the function takes the name of the range but not the value in it.
The range location of those inputs is manually assigned and later on store there the outcome of a formula.
Below the code I have highlighted the part with the problem
Any idea about how I can apply the range value into the function?

```
   Sub my_range()

   Dim RngWidth As Long, RngHeight As Long

   Dim MyAverage As Variant, MyStDev As Variant, MyMax As Variant, MyMin As
     Variant, MyCount As Variant

Dim StckReturns As Range

Dim MyAverage1 As Variant, MyStDev1 As Variant


Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select

Selection.End(xlUp).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

RngWidth = Selection.Columns.Count

RngHeight = Selection.Rows.Count

ActiveCell.Offset(0, RngWidth).Range("a1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Daily Return"

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("a1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=StockReturn(R[-1]C[-1],RC[-1])"

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(RngHeight - 3, 0))

Set StckReturns = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(RngHeight - 3, 0))

MyAverage = InputBox("Where do you want the Average?")

MyStDev = InputBox("Where do you want the Standard Deviation?")

Range(MyAverage).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(StckReturns.Value)

Range(MyStDev).Value = WorksheetFunction.StDev(StckReturns.Value)

MyAverage1 = Range(MyAverage).Value

MyStDev1 = Range(MyStDev).Value

ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("a1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Scaled Return"

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("a1").Select

***ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ScaledReturns(RC[-1],myaverage1,MyStDev1)"***

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(RngHeight - 3, 0))


End Sub

Function StockReturn(IniPrice As Double, FinPrice As Double) As Double

StockReturn = (FinPrice - IniPrice) / IniPrice

End Function

Function ScaledReturns(MyReturn As Variant, AverageReturn As Variant, StDevReturn As Variant) As Double

ScaledReturns = (MyReturn - AverageReturn) / StDevReturn

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to concatenate the literal values into the formula string like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ScaledReturns(RC[-1]," & myaverage1 & "," & MyStDev1 & ")"
```

or use the address of the ranges:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ScaledReturns(RC[-1]," & Range(myaverage).Address(referencestyle:=xlR1C1) & "," & Range(MyStDev).Address(referencestyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"
```